# php страница обрабатывается сервером не полностью

Tags: php, ubuntu

Имею вот такой код:

```
echo "Step 3 - Create parent table ... successfully!" . "<br /><br />";
} else {
    echo "Step 3 - Create parent table ... failed" . "<br /><br />";
        }


echo "Хей";
echo "Хей";
echo "Хей";
echo "Хей";



// ***************************** ПОДГОТОВИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ЭТАП ***********************************

// получаю список всех дат изменений в logger
$query_data=$conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT data FROM userlogger ORDER BY entry ASC"); // ДАТЫ СОРТИРОВАНЫ ПО ВОЗРАСТАНИЮ!!!

while ($row=$query_data->fetch_row()) {
       $exist_dates[]=$row[0]; // exist_dates это перечень уникальных всех дат в logger
}
unset($row); // чтобы избежать конфликтов из-за повторного использования переменной $row

echo "Хрен";

// добавляю в массив дата техническую дату $parent_tablename
$exist_dates[]=$parent_tablename;

// сортирую массив дат по возрастанию
sort($exist_dates, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

В результате на странице выводится:

```
Step 3 - Create parent table ... successfully!

ХейХейХейХей
```

Идущий код после последнего "Хей" не выполняется. Специально добавил вывод "Хрен"!!!

В чем может быть причина? Сейчас эту страницу обрабатывает apache на Ubuntu. 
На Openserver эта же страница отлично работает.

Comment: отображение ошибок включите и узнаете причину

Comment: Не подскажете как включить?

Comment: ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting('E_ALL');

Comment: И, самое главное, в скрипте выше приведенного вами куска кода подключение к базе данных происходит?

Comment: `query()` - Проверьте эту функцию. Возможно ошибка в ней.Например вместо `mysqli_query` у вас там `mysql_query`

Comment: Ошибка оказалась в "SELECT DISTINCT data FROM userlogger ORDER BY entry ASC". Забил этот запрос в sql сервер, ругается на ORDER BY entry ASC. Убрал параметр - все заработало